# Unexpected end of input | BIND9

Tags: server, 20.04, dns, bind

I'm getting the error from below when starting `bind9` (I'm using Ubuntu `20.04.3 LTS` and bind `9.16.1`):

[image]

I'm almost sure that the issue is related to `/var/cache/bind/managed-keys.bind` but I don't know where the problem is exactly.

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Delete `/var/cache/bind/managed-keys.bind` and `/var/cache/bind/managed-keys.bind.jnl`, and restart bind with `systemctl restart bind9`.

These two files will get auto-created with the missing key within KEYDATA.